# Validation of three text boxes, including phone number

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation

How do I add ASP.NET validation in C# all three text boxes aren't empty and the phone number has the format of DDDD-DDDD where D is 0 – 9?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to solve this problem yourself?  The documentation is easy to find:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx

You need to use a required field validator -- something like this:

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
         id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
         ErrorMessage="Required!" 
         ControlToValidate="txtFirstName">
```

You will also want a regular expression validator, something like:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
   runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhoneNumber" 
    ErrorMessage="wrong!" 
    ValidationExpression="^\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

NB The toolbox for reg expression has many built in, including most phone number formats.  I would just use one of those.

[image: editor]

Comment: Maybe `\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d`? [Your means 8 letters d](http://www.rubular.com/r/I3LQBIsNAa)

Answer (score 0):

Use [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic3) and [ReguralExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic6) controls.

The [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic3) server control makes sure that the user enters something into the field that it is associated with in the form. You need to tie the [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic3) to each control that is a required field in the form.

The [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx#aspnet-validateaspnetservercontrols_topic6) server control is a validation control that enables you to check the user's input based on a pattern defined by a regular expression.

---

Refer to:

[Validating ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" /></td>
<td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
<td><asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ValidationExpression="..." Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="group">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator></td>
</tr>
<!-- do the same 2 times more -->
</table>
```

[The RegEx](http://www.rubular.com/r/Acr8utPqtG) should be I guess:

```
^\d{4,4}-\d{4,4}$
```

or (if you don't want to make a variable number of digits, e.g. 2 to 4):

```
^\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d$
```

what means:

```
line begin
4 digits, not more or less
dash
4 digits, not more or less
line end
```

Comment: How do I validate the phone number to XXXX-XXXX ?